# numpy transform vector to binary matrix

Tags: python, numpy

I'm looking for a clean way to transform a vector of integers into a 2D array of binary values, where ones are in the columns corresponding to the values of the vector taken as indices

i.e.

```
v = np.array([1, 5, 3])
C = np.zeros((v.shape[0], v.max()))
```

what i'm looking for is the way to transform C into this:

```
array([[ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.]])
```

i've come up with this:

```
C[np.arange(v.shape[0]), v.T-1] = 1
```

but i wonder if there is less verbose / more elegant approach?

thanks!

**UPDATE**

Thanks for your comments! There was an error in my code: if there is 0 in `v`, it will put 1 into wrong place (last column). Instead, i have to expand categorical data to include 0.

jrennie's answer is a big win for large vectors as long as you deal with sparse matrices exclusively. In my case i need to return an array for compatibility, and the conversion levels the advantage entirely - see both solutions:

```
    def permute_array(vector):
        permut = np.zeros((vector.shape[0], vector.max()+1))
        permut[np.arange(vector.shape[0]), vector] = 1
        return permut

    def permute_matrix(vector):
        indptr = range(vector.shape[0]+1)
        ones = np.ones(vector.shape[0])
        permut = sparse.csr_matrix((ones, vector, indptr))
        return permut

    In [193]: vec = np.random.randint(1000, size=1000)
    In [194]: np.all(permute_matrix(vec) == permute_array(vec))
    Out[194]: True

    In [195]: %timeit permute_array(vec)
    100 loops, best of 3: 3.49 ms per loop

    In [196]: %timeit permute_matrix(vec)
    1000 loops, best of 3: 422 µs per loop
```

Now, adding conversion:

```
    def permute_matrix(vector):
        indptr = range(vector.shape[0]+1)
        ones = np.ones(vector.shape[0])
        permut = sparse.csr_matrix((ones, vector, indptr))
        return permut.toarray()

    In [198]: %timeit permute_matrix(vec)
    100 loops, best of 3: 4.1 ms per loop
```

Comment: Your way looks good to me! You can do without the `.T` though

Comment: You are trying to implement a permutation matrix. I think your solution is fine. As Mr E said, without T. See also this question in[https://stackoverflow.com/][SO]. Was wondering if there is some function in ´scipy.linalg´ that implements the permutation matrix.

Comment: @Tengis Your link doesn't work.

Comment: @askewchan sorry about that. Here is the  [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11649577/how-to-invert-a-permutation-array-in-numpy)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A drawback to your solution is that it is inefficient for large values. If you want a more efficient representation, create scipy sparse matrix, e.g.:

```
import scipy.sparse
import numpy

indices = [1, 5, 3]
indptr = range(len(indices)+1)
data = numpy.ones(len(indices))
matrix = scipy.sparse.csr_matrix((data, indices, indptr))
```

Read about the [Yale Format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix#Yale_format) and [scipy's csr_matrix](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.13.0/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.html) to better understand the objects (indices, indptr, data) and usage.

Note that I am not subtracting 1 from the indices in the above code. Use `indices = numpy.array([1, 5, 3])-1` if that's what you want.