# Rearrange numpy vector according to mapping rule

Tags: python, numpy

I have a vector withs 0s and 1s. I want to have a new vector with rearranged values, whereas I have another vector with a mapping rule:

Example:

```
input: 1,0,0,1
rule: 0,3,2,1
after mapping:1,1,0,0
```

The mapping vector determines for each index at which index in the new vector the value can be found.

How do I do that?

Comment: I do not understand the mapping rule. Did you mean 0, 3, 1, 2?

Comment: `a=np.asarray([1,0,0,1]); b=np.asarray([0,3,1,2]); a[b]`

Comment: @Bort This doesn't do what the OP wants: see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say `a` is the original array and `b` is the mapping rule. Since the mapping rule says "at which index in the **new** vector the value can be found", you need to compute `a[c]` where `c` is the **inverse** of the permutation `b`. The computation of inverse permutation is [addressed in detail elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11649577/how-to-invert-a-permutation-array-in-numpy), so I'll pick one of solutions from there:

```
c = np.zeros(b.size, b.dtype)
c[b] = np.arange(b.size) 
new_array = a[c]
```

Example: if a is `[7, 8, 9]` and b is `[1, 2, 0]`, this returns `[9, 7, 8]`. Let's check:

- 7 went to position 1,
- 8 went to position 2,
- 9 went to position 0

The result is correct.

---

If you did `a[b]` as suggested by [Bort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36176769/rearrange-numpy-vector-according-to-mapping-rule#comment59990725_36176769), the result would be `[8, 9, 7]`, which is different. Indeed, in this version the entries of `b`  say where the numbers **came from** in the original array:

- 8 came from position 1
- 9 came from position 2
- 7 came from position 0

---

To muddle the matter, the example you gave is a permutation that is equal to its inverse, so the distinction is lost.