# Efficiently define an implicit Numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array

`A` and `B` are Numpy arrays of common shape `[n1,n2,n3]`. The values of `B` are all integers in `[0,n3)`. I want `A` to "invert" `B` in the sense that each value of `A` satisfies `A[i,j,B[i,j,k]]=k` for all `i,j,k` in the appropriate ranges. While it's obvious how to do this with for loops, I suspect that there is a clever one-liner using fancy indexing. Does anyone see it?

Comment: I think your question implies that for each `i` and `j`, the 1d slice `B[i,j,:]` is a permutation of `range(n3)`, otherwise the "inverse" doesn't exist.  Is that correct?

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser that's correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are two methods.

---

The first method is a one-liner: `A = B.argsort(axis=-1)`

Here's an example.  `B` has shape (3, 5, 7) and for each fixed `i` and `j`, `B[i,j,:]` is a permutation of `range(B.shape[2])`.

```
In [386]: B
Out[386]: 
array([[[1, 5, 4, 6, 2, 3, 0],
        [6, 5, 3, 4, 2, 1, 0],
        [4, 5, 0, 3, 1, 2, 6],
        [0, 5, 6, 3, 2, 1, 4],
        [4, 1, 5, 2, 6, 3, 0]],

       [[2, 6, 0, 1, 5, 4, 3],
        [3, 2, 4, 0, 1, 5, 6],
        [3, 4, 6, 5, 1, 2, 0],
        [4, 6, 3, 0, 2, 5, 1],
        [0, 3, 1, 6, 4, 5, 2]],

       [[0, 3, 6, 2, 1, 5, 4],
        [3, 1, 2, 4, 6, 0, 5],
        [1, 3, 5, 6, 4, 0, 2],
        [4, 1, 6, 0, 2, 3, 5],
        [6, 4, 5, 1, 0, 3, 2]]])

In [387]: A = B.argsort(axis=-1)

In [388]: A
Out[388]: 
array([[[6, 0, 4, 5, 2, 1, 3],
        [6, 5, 4, 2, 3, 1, 0],
        [2, 4, 5, 3, 0, 1, 6],
        [0, 5, 4, 3, 6, 1, 2],
        [6, 1, 3, 5, 0, 2, 4]],

       [[2, 3, 0, 6, 5, 4, 1],
        [3, 4, 1, 0, 2, 5, 6],
        [6, 4, 5, 0, 1, 3, 2],
        [3, 6, 4, 2, 0, 5, 1],
        [0, 2, 6, 1, 4, 5, 3]],

       [[0, 4, 3, 1, 6, 5, 2],
        [5, 1, 2, 0, 3, 6, 4],
        [5, 0, 6, 1, 4, 2, 3],
        [3, 1, 4, 5, 0, 6, 2],
        [4, 3, 6, 5, 1, 2, 0]]])
```

Verify the desired property by sampling a few values.

```
In [389]: A[0, 0, B[0, 0, 0]]
Out[389]: 0

In [390]: A[0, 0, B[0, 0, 1]]
Out[390]: 1

In [391]: A[0, 0, B[0, 0, :]]
Out[391]: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])

In [392]: A[2, 3, B[2, 3, :]]
Out[392]: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
```

---

The second method has a lower time complexity than using `argsort`, but it is a three-liner rather than a one-liner.  I'll use the same `B` as above.

Create `A`, but with no values assigned yet.

```
In [393]: A = np.empty_like(B)
```

Create index arrays for each dimension of `B`.

```
In [394]: i, j, k = np.ogrid[[slice(n) for n in B.shape]]  # or np.ix_(*[range(n) for n in B.shape])
```

This is the cool part.  Do the assignment exactly as you wrote it in the question.

```
In [395]: A[i, j, B[i, j, k]] = k
```

Verify that we have the same `A` as above.

```
In [396]: A
Out[396]: 
array([[[6, 0, 4, 5, 2, 1, 3],
        [6, 5, 4, 2, 3, 1, 0],
        [2, 4, 5, 3, 0, 1, 6],
        [0, 5, 4, 3, 6, 1, 2],
        [6, 1, 3, 5, 0, 2, 4]],

       [[2, 3, 0, 6, 5, 4, 1],
        [3, 4, 1, 0, 2, 5, 6],
        [6, 4, 5, 0, 1, 3, 2],
        [3, 6, 4, 2, 0, 5, 1],
        [0, 2, 6, 1, 4, 5, 3]],

       [[0, 4, 3, 1, 6, 5, 2],
        [5, 1, 2, 0, 3, 6, 4],
        [5, 0, 6, 1, 4, 2, 3],
        [3, 1, 4, 5, 0, 6, 2],
        [4, 3, 6, 5, 1, 2, 0]]])
```

---

After poking around some more on SO, I see that both these methods appear in answers to the question ["How to invert a permutation array in numpy"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11649577/how-to-invert-a-permutation-array-in-numpy).  The only thing really new here is doing the inversion along one axis of a three-dimensional array.