# Numpy quickly invert indices and values

Tags: python, numpy

I want to turn A into B:

```
A = [0, 4, 1, 3, 2]
B = [0, 2, 4, 3, 1]
```

B represents turning the values of A into indices and the indices of A into values. How do I do this quickly with a numpy array A?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to invert a permutation array in numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11649577/how-to-invert-a-permutation-array-in-numpy)

Comment: From the duplicate question, pick the `invert_permutation` function at the end of [Ali's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25535723/1782792) (that is, you do `import numpy as np; a = np.array([0, 4, 1, 3, 2]); b = np.empty_like(a); b[a] = np.arange(len(a)); print(b)` and you get `[0 2 4 3 1]`).

Comment: `A=np.array([0, 4, 1, 3, 2])` and then it's just `A[A]`