# Using batched input with tf.math.invert_permutation

Tags: python, tensorflow, permutation

I have a tensor holding a batch of permutations of the integers `0` to `time-1` which e.g. has the shape

```
[batch,time]
```

Now I want to invert all these permutations to get a tensor of the same shape.
I know this can be done using [`tf.math.invert_permutation`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/math/invert_permutation) for a single tensor of shape `[time]`, but that function does not support batched input. It will through an error if the input tensor has more than one dimension.

What can I do to make [`tf.math.invert_permutation`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/math/invert_permutation) work with batched input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it to use the `tf.data.Dataset` API.

Following is how I will implement it.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Instead of using the Dataset API, I can also just use `tf.map_fn`. Good idea actually! I am still a little concerned about performance, but its pretty simple to implement and get's me going for now.
I am using:
`tf.reshape(tf.map_fn(fn=lambda x: tf.math.invert_permutation(x), elems=tf.reshape(x, [-1, x.shape[len(x.shape)-1]])), x.shape)`

Comment: I am actually not sure exactly about the performance numbers, but I would say that the prefered way to use the input data pipeline is using `tf.data.Dataset` API as per Tensorflow.

Comment: I did some tests with this, and in my case it was horribly slow to use `map` here. Instead, I ended up using a `tf.range` in combination with `tf.scatter_nd`, and with this implementing the simple numpy solution at the end of this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25535723/2766231.